# Are there any (commonly used/seriously proposed) discrete distributions that are "pathological"?

Tags: probability, distributions

An example of a commonly used "[pathological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_(mathematics))" continuous distribution is the [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), which is considered to be "pathological" as it has no defined mean or variance. It can be defined as the ratio of two normally distributed random variables with mean 0, or analytically about a point $x_0$ as

$$f(x; x_0,\gamma) = \frac{1}{\pi\gamma \left[1 + \left(\frac{x - x_0}{\gamma}\right)^2\right]} = { 1 \over \pi \gamma } \left[ { \gamma^2 \over (x - x_0)^2 + \gamma^2  } \right].$$

[image: Example Plot]

As you are all undoubtedly aware, despite "obviously" appearing to have a "mean" value at $x_0$, the expectation value of the mean (that is, $\int x f(x; x_0,\gamma)\,\mathrm{d}x$) is itself another Cauchy distribution; likewise, its variance is also undefined. It is perhaps therefore the canonical example of a "pathological" distribution (Wikipedia's words!) -- or at least, the only one that I'm aware of, although I accept that it is very well behaved in many other important aspects.

Whilst obviously there are an arbitrarily large number of "pathological" distributions that could be constructed, to my mind this one is of interest because it is frequently studied, and can be experimentally realised -- in resonances in particular. For example, in particle physics, it's often known as a Breit-Wigner distribution and describes the cross section for a particular reaction occurring and particle being made (i.e. if one plots $\sigma$ in barn against $\sqrt{S}$ in GeV, one finds that particles on mass shell -- i.e. actually created -- are described by this distribution).

My question is this: while I am sure that it is "relatively" easy to construct a discrete distribution that does not have a well defined mean and/or variance (feel free to try!), are there any that have been proposed, studied, or can be experimentally realised, for example by some combination of oddly shaped, oddly coloured, multidimensional dice?

Comment: Catchy is a perfecty "proper" distribution. How do you define pathological? By not having mean and variance?

Comment: "Badly behaved," "seriously proposed," and "crop up in odd places" are too vague to be answerable in this format.  "Pathological" is very much in the eye of the beholder: it's purely a personal, subjective characterization.

Comment: Oh phooey! I was writing an answer about the schizophrenic St. Petersburg random variable $Z$ that takes on values $\pm 2^n$ with equal probability $\frac 12\cdot 2^{-n}$ (and thus has a symmetric pmf) but for which the mean is undefined for precisely the same reason as the mean is defined for Cauchy random variables when this question was put on hold. For those curious about the name (which I just made up), $X = \log_2 |Z|$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $\frac 12$.

Comment: Were I to edit this to say that by "pathological" I mean no single mean and variance, would that be okay?

Comment: @Landak Or just leave out "pathological" altogether and state explicitly that you're interested in all distributions which do not have finite means.

Comment: See, *inter alia*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_negative_binomial_distribution, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%E2%80%93Mandelbrot_law.

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350363/discrete-random-variable-with-infinite-expectation